# Can I pass yaw pitch roll instead of quaternion(for imu) in robot_localiztion package?

Tags: imu, navigation, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My imu is giving me only yaw,pitch and roll. How can i pass that into robot_localization package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281285/can-i-pass-yaw-pitch-roll-instead-of-quaternion(for-imu)-in-robot_localiztion-package?/) by [khansaadbinhasan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33367/khansaadbinhasan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 94 on 2018-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please refer to the [wiki's description of the sensor configuration parameter](http://docs.ros.org/lunar/api/robot_localization/html/state_estimation_nodes.html#sensor-config).

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1